# migrating from django-cms beta3 to 2.1.3 (stable)

Tags: python, django, django-south, django-cms

Hey guys,
Im trying to migrate django-cms from version 2.1.0 beta3 to 2.1.3 (stable), i have read many posts that recommend South for this, unfortunately i have never done anything with south, and i didn't have it installed when creating my projects, so i have followed many solutions that include running:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

on the old version and then installing the new version and run:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

however this does not work, because django throws the following error:

```
no such column: cms_page.limit_visibility_in_menu
```

so i was wondering if anyone has another solution they would like to share.
btw im using python 2.7 and Django 1.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this sequence when db changes and we need to do schemamigration using South:

```
    ./manage.py schemamigration your_app_name --auto
```

Note, than database *should* fit your models, otherwise you'll get errors.

Then, after you get success message and invitation to migration, you do:

```
    ./manage.py migrate
```

That's it. Backup you database before, so you can rewind. Then you just will need to restore your dumped database and delete failed migration file from migrations directory.